# MOSFET Floating Drain

Tags: mosfet

I'm trying to power a board through both usb & a 9V battery (with the usb taking precedence) with a P channel MOSFET, a schottky diode & a pull down resistor. I'm confident this will work with just a battery, since the gate of the PMOS is pulled down and so the MOSFET will be on.

[image: Load Sharing Circuit]

What I'm concerned about is when a USB cable is connected. Primarily because the battery is 9V and runs through a DC/DC converter which is disabled once the USB is connected. So the +5Vbat will actually be low when the MOSFET is off (gate & source will be at ~ +5V). I know having a floating source or gate can be bad/damaging; should I be concerned about any current leakage when the drain is ambiguous?

Comment: "the +5Vbat will actually be low or floating" Will it be low, or will it be floating?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Low, sorry to be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit does not work as you are expecting.
In case you unplug 5Vusb: you cannot rely that source of mosfet is connected to 5V. 
MOSFET "has" diode between drain and source, and that is what plays role here.
This is scheme of standard P-MOSFET:
[image]

So, when I redraw your scheme, this is what is going on in your circuit in reality:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the lesson on the body diode, I didn't know about that behaviour between the drain and source.

Comment: I couldn't recall the name of that diode. So I thank you to remind me, that it is body diode ;)